# mongoose router find by reference properety

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am working in my project I already wrote the server.js file for backend
this is my mongoose schema and model

```
const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
title: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
isbn: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
author: {
  type: String,
  //required: true
},
description: {
  type: String
},
published_date: {
  type: Date
},
publisher: {
  type: String
},
updated_date: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
}
});

// make data model from schema
const Book = mongoose.model('book', BookSchema);
```

this is my router

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {


 Book.findById(req.params.id)
.then(book => res.json(book.title))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nobookfound: 'No Book found' }));
});
```

How can I pass Book.isbn through get request to get Book.title

Comment: didnt understand your question

Comment: My question how i useb book.isbn search parameter instead of id in this code                           
  router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {


 Book.findById(req.params.id)
.then(book => res.json(book.title))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nobookfound: 'No Book found' }));
});

Answer (score 0):

just use the findOne method

```
Book.findOne({isbn:"pass isbn value here"})
.then(book => res.json(book.title))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nobookfound: 'No Book found' }));
});
```

Comment: so the full code will be                                                                                       
   `code` router.get('/:isbn', (req, res) => {


 Book.findOne({isbn:" isbn "})
.then(book => res.json(book.title))
.catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nobookfound: 'No Book found' }));
});
});    ` code`                                                                                                                                        is this right

Comment: just try and let me kow

Comment: I tried following Code `router.get('/:isbn', (req, res) => {
  
 
  
  Book.findOne({isbn:"isbn"})
  .then(book => res.json(book.title))
  .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nobookfound: 'No Book found' }));
});` i tested by Insomina i sent the following get request `http://localhost:5000/20` and I got following reply `{
 "nobookfound": "No Book found"
}`

Comment: well.. this is the code you need why it fails related to something else

Comment: i tried but it is not working